# Swift2 push notification foreground play sound

Tags: apple-push-notifications, swift2, ios9

Can someone please help me with playing a sound when my app receives a push notification and is active in the foreground? I can hack it but isn't there more elegant built in functionality that is made available to the developer by Apple. I am using Swift2.

Thanks

Comment: An explanation for the down vote would be nice..Apple have not updated their documentation to cater for their new programming language so how can I learn with out asking?

Comment: When the app is in the foreground the notification won't be displayed but it's passed in `didReceiveRemoteNotification`. You have to play the sound programmatically.

Comment: Yes Vadian thats how I eventually played the sound; answer is below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//Declare a AVaudioplayer var
var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

//Call this function whenever you want to play the sound
func playSound()
    {
        do {
            if let bundle = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("mySound", ofType: "wav")
             {
                let alertSound = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: bundle)
                try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
                try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
                try audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: alertSound)
                    audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
                    audioPlayer.play()
                print("Playing")
            }
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
```